# Redis not connecting in production

Tags: node.js, express, redis, vercel

writing this after a day of struggling. My redis instance isn't getting connected in production. I'm using redis for a rate-limitter function but it wasn't getting connected remotely. My app is on vercel. I thought I fixed it by defining env variables in vercel but still it's there.

Here's the error:

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). Refer to \"maxRetriesPerRequest\" option for details.","reason":{"errorType":"MaxRetriesPerRequestError","errorMessage":"Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). Refer to \"maxRetriesPerRequest\" option for details.","stack":["MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). Refer to \"maxRetriesPerRequest\" option for details.","    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/api/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis/event_handler.js:182:37)","    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:26)","    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)","    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:350:12)","    at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). Refer to \"maxRetriesPerRequest\" option for details.","    at process.<anonymous> (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1276:17)","    at process.emit (node:events:529:35)","    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:149:20)","    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:283:27)","    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:32)"]}
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown
```

This is my rate-limitter and it is working all fine locally:

```
const redis = require("ioredis");
const moment = require("moment");
require("dotenv").config();

// const redisClient = redis.createClient({
//   password: "N1k4jWYNWCLioAskvSmq6rSQmGCjtEpx",
//   host: "redis-16335.c301.ap-south-1-1.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com",
//   port: 16335,
// });
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
  port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
});

const RATELIMIT_DURATION_IN_SECONDS = 60;
const NUMBER_OF_REQUEST_ALLOWED = 10;

module.exports = {
  rateLimitter: async (req, res, next) => {
    const userId = req.user.id;
    const currentTime = moment().unix();
    // console.log(currentTime);

    const result = await redisClient.hgetall(userId);
    if (Object.keys(result).length === 0) {
      await redisClient.hset(userId, {
        createdAt: currentTime,
        count: 1,
      });
      return next();
    }
    if (result) {
      let diff = currentTime - result["createdAt"];

      if (diff > RATELIMIT_DURATION_IN_SECONDS) {
        await redisClient.hset(userId, {
          createdAt: currentTime,
          count: 1,
        });
        return next();
      }
    }
    if (result["count"] >= NUMBER_OF_REQUEST_ALLOWED) {
      return res.status(429).json({
        success: false,
        message: "user-ratelimited",
      });
    } else {
      await redisClient.hset(userId, {
        count: parseInt(result["count"]) + 1,
      });
      return next();
    }
  },
};
```

Your help would be really appreciated folks. I really am on the verge of giving up on this.

Thank you so much in advance.